# How to query data from GAE datastore with the value escaped?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I have a entity saved in the DB with the property "Name" using value "Test".

I want to know, how to get this entity with a query with the value being lowercase.

This is the query to execute: `query = "Name == test"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a new indexed property, e.g. name_lowercase that only has the altered (lowercased) values.

Comment: So, there is no option to have a query to fetch the data that is already saved the DB?

Comment: There isn't a query to do all the work you want as an index doesn't exist for the query you want to do.  However, you can run a Dataflow job to fetch all the entities and do the matching yourself.